# Why doesn't this fixed-point computation stop?

Tags: haskell, infinite-loop, lazy-evaluation, fixpoint-combinators, infinite-recursion

I am new to Haskell, and I have the following code:

```
second (x:y:xs) = y : second xs  -- returns every second element of a list
second _ = []

xs = [1,2,3,4] ++ second xs
```

I expect `xs` to be evaluated to `[1,2,3,4,2,4,4]`, because that is the fixed point, i.e. `[1,2,3,4,2,4,4] == [1,2,3,4] ++ second [1,2,3,4,2,4,4]`.

However, when I try to evaluate `xs` in GHCi, I get

```
Prelude> xs
[1,2,3,4,2,4,4
```

but it doesn't stop computing.

Could anyone explain why this doesn't stop, and is there a simple way to make the computation stop and return `[1,2,3,4,2,4,4]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[1,2,3,4,2,4,4] ++ []` is *a* fixed point of `([1,2,3,4] ++) . second`, but it is not *the least* fixed point.

That is `[1,2,3,4,2,4,4] ++ undefined`, which is *smaller*. It is *smaller* in the sense that it is less defined than the first one.

The first one is more defined in that it has its 7th tail defined whereas the second's 7th tail is `undefined`.

That's the general outlook. But specifically we can follow the computations step by step, naming all the interim values and expanding the definition, and we will find out that the "get" point on the result catches up with the "put" point which is initially farther ahead, but the "get" point is twice faster than "put". So that when they meet there's nothing there yet that we've put there which we could get.

Thus the computation gets stuck, waiting for something to appear where there's nothing, and there's nothing that could put anything there.

The only way to avoid this is to put `take 7` on top of it.

On an unrelated note I'd call that function `seconds`, not `second`.

---

So it goes like this:

```
xs = [1,2,3,4] ++ second xs

              a b c         (_:a:p) = xs = [1,2,3,4]++second xs
              ↓ ↓ ↓         (_:b:q) = p  = [    3,4,2]++second p
   =  1 2 3 4 2 4 4         (_:c:r) = q  = [        2,4]++second q
        ↓   ↓   ↓   ↓                 r  = [            4]++second r
        a   b   c    
      ↑   ↑   ↑   ↑                  r = drop 2 q = second q = 
      xs  p   q   r                    = second (2:4:r) = 4:second r
```

`head r` is well defined, it is

```
r = drop 2 q = second q 
             = second (_:c:r) 
             = c:second r
head r = c = 4
tail r =
```

but then we need to find `tail r`. Is it a `(:)` data node? Is it `[]`?

```
       = tail (c:second r)
       = second r               -- (1)
       = second (c:second r)
       = case (c:second r) of
           (x:y:z) -> y:second z
           []      -> []
       = case (second r) of     -- (2)
           (y:z) -> y:second z
```

and so to find out what `second r` ( `(1)` ) is, we need to find out ***what `second r` ( `(2)` ) is***.

We're stuck.

Comment: A small demonstration https://gist.github.com/pedrofurla/ffc61559d7a4fba74d4c42c6da0c3832 I was going to add to an answer, but to be complete it would need to go through evaluating everything manual. It would tedious.

Comment: @pedrofurla you show the expansion of `second [1,2,3,4]` there, not of `xs`. :)

Comment: Yes. It demonstrates why it doesn't terminate. Doesn't it?

Comment: I don't know. I'd have to follow the expansion of `xs`. I'm writing it right now. :)

Comment: > The only way to avoid this is to put take 7 on top of it.
Is there a way to count how many elements we have until "the end", i.e. `second` returns `[]`?

Comment: `take 7` is not the only choice. You could also define your own fixpoint operator that worked by repeated application and equality checking, e.g. `fixEq :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> (a -> a); fixEq f guess | guess' == guess = guess | otherwise = fixEq f guess' where guess' = f guess`.

Comment: It just occurred to me. The ideal example is xs = [] ++ second xs.

Comment: @DanielWagner I tried `fixEq $ ([1,2,3,4] ++) . second` bbut it wanted a Show instance for `[a] ->[a]`. how was I supposed to call it?

Comment: @DanielWagner Is there a linear time solution?

Comment: @eivour "how to count" the only way I can think of is to write our own Haskell interpreter that'd do that. of course it wouldn't be able to do that _always_,  because of the halting problem, but perhaps sometimes. if it did succeed, that would break the requirement (I think it is) for Haskell to find _least_ fixed points; but we'd probably give this operation a different name, like Daniel did above.

Comment: @WillNess Call it with any (finite, fully-defined) list as `guess`, e.g. `fixEq (([1,2,3,4]++) . second) []`.

Comment: @eivour Linear with respect to what? What is the input that's changing and whose size we can freely vary? If it is the `[1,2,3,4]` that you plan to vary, then you can get O(n\*log(n)^2) using [Brent's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Brent's_algorithm) for cycle detection in the implementation of `fixEq`, or O(n\*log(n)) using an algorithm specialized to this problem rather than a generic fixpoint operator. I don't see an obvious way to build the O(n\*log(n))-big output in less than O(n\*log(n)) time.

Comment: @DanielWagner I meant linear with the length N of input list, that is `[1,2,3,4]` in the above case. In the above `fixEq` implementation, I thought we would have to make O(log N) comparison of lists of length O(N), resulting in O(NlogN) total time complexity.

Comment: @DanielWagner Isn't the output length O(N)? That is, N + N/2 + N/4 + ... = 2N, approximately.

Comment: @eivour You're almost right; except I believe you are making O(log(n)) comparisons of lists of length O(n\*log(n)).

Comment: @eivour Err... yes! My math is off in both of my last comments. Here is a corrected one: the current implementation is O(n\*log(n)). Brent's algorithm has the same asymptotic complexity (but is probably faster anyway). No generic fixpoint algorithm can do asymptotically better. A specialized algorithm (rather than generic one) can get you to O(n).

Comment: @DanielWagner but now `fixEq (([1,2,3,4,5,6]++) . id) []` hangs. so your _very clever I don't know how you've come up with it_ thing only works for the "contracting" second functions. (of course that was the question...)

Comment: @WillNess I think "contracting" probably isn't the right property. For example, `fixEq (\x -> (x^2+4)/(2*x))` terminates every `Double` I could think to try and I'm not sure what "contracting" could possibly mean for `Double`. The right property seems somewhat hard to concisely describe, though.

Comment: @DanielWagner I now get `fixEq (([1,2,3,4]++) . second) $ take n [41..] == [1,2,3,4,2,4,4,48]` for all `n >= 8` that I could test. it produces correct result for `n < 8`. so making the first guess becomes a conundrum in itself. "will `[]` always work? can we be sure?"

Comment: and for `(([1..16]++) . second)` it's `[41..72]`. so it starts at twice the length  for some reason.

Comment: @WillNess Like `fix`, `fixEq` only promises to return *a* fixpoint, and not necessarily *the fixpoint you have in mind*.

Comment: @DanielWagner good point indeed!  BTW I've never realized before that we can get to _a_ fixpoint of a list-creating function by iterating it from a starting candidate, just as we can with the number-valued functions like `sin`. 8-)

Comment: @pedrofurla I've finally edited with the specific steps. turns out the culprit is `r = 4:second r` as the last "cons cell" of the list.

Comment: @WillNess :) That was my point! Lol https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418700/why-doesnt-this-fixed-point-computation-stop/69418812?noredirect=1#comment122697555_69418812

Comment: @pedrofurla it's not the same though. `xs = [] ++ second xs = second xs` is not `xs = 4:second xs`. :) both don't work of course, but I wanted to see exactly and specifically what happens _here_.

Comment: Yeah, value-wise the are not the same. Morally they are somewhat equivalent. ⊥

Answer (score 4):

Another more intuitive way to see it is that the `[]` (end of the list) has to come from somewhere. The `second` function will only return `[]` once it encounters a `[]` in the input, so you end up with a chicken and egg situation. In this case the `[]` is never produced and therefore the computation can never stop.

Comment: `second` returns `[]` whenever there are less than two elements in the list, so repeated application of `second` eventually returns `[]`.

Comment: Not really , eg `xs = [] ++ second xs`.

Comment: @eivour For the input to have less than two inputs, it must *already have* a `[]`, as even a singleton list `[x]` is actually `x:[]` behind the scenes. And that `[]` has to come from somewhere -- the argument "`second` produces `[]` because it sees a `[]` that came from `second`" leads to the question, "but why did a `[]` come from `second`"... an infinite regress. For the `[]` to come from somewhere in a finite argument, it has to come from something other than a recursive call to `second`.

Comment: @eivour ...and to be explicit about it, while Haskell does infinite *values* just fine, it doesn't do infinite *arguments* at all (here I use "arguments" in the sense of my previous comment, not in the sense of "function arguments").

Comment: @DanielWagner turns out the culprit here is `r = 4:second r` as the last "cons cell". I've edited my answer with the specifics. :)

Comment: @eivour This recursive definition never calls `second` on a list with less than two elements. Eventually there are less than two "already computed" elements, but at that point it's not a list that concretely ends after less than two elements, but rather a list that ends in a thunk, and forcing that thunk never yields a constructor. You're not starting at the concrete list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and expanding it in steps to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4]` and then `[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4]`; you start with `1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : <thunk>`, forcing that to `1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 2 : 4 : <thunk>`. There's never a `[]`.